# SELECT Schema.Table.Column -> Column from another table WHERE

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, business-objects, intersystems-cache

`Business Objects` is generating the following `SQL` for my query

```
SELECT Schema.Table.Column->"Column from another table"
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE  ...
```

The `"Column"` in `Schema.Table.Column` contains the code `"A1234"`, but because of the `"->"` it's actually looking up the description against another table.

Because `"-"` and `">"` are frequently used in the documentation, I cannot search to find out what the **->** does.  I am assuming it's something to do with aliasing, but I cannot find reference to **->** anywhere.  Can someone please at least tell me what I should search to find understanding for **->**?

BO version is 6.1b, data source CACHE (don't know the version), UNV was created by a company years ago that are no longer involved, seeing this in Thick Client (which later became known as DESKI).

Comment: Can you specify the version of BusinessObjects, the data source (vendor and version) you're using (I suspect that you've created a universe?) and which product in the BusinessObjects stack where you're seeing this (BusinessObjects is a set of products/clients)?

Comment: BO 6.1b (don't laugh), data source CACHE (don't know the version), UNV was created by a company years ago that are no longer involved, seeing this in Thick Client (which later became known as DESKI).

Comment: I suggest you update your question with that information, so others don't miss it, and perhaps add a tag `intersystems-cache` for cache as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an SQL operator that's defined in Caché SQL and is used as an *implicit join*.

Reference:

- [Symbols Used in Caché SQL](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20091/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_symbols)
- [Using Caché SQL (PDF)](http://docs.intersystems.com/documentation/cache/20082/pdfs/GSQL.pdf), par. 18.1 Implicit Joins (Arrow Syntax)

Comment: Good job Kristof, my first mistake was assuming this was a BO issue.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Paul, @Kristof's answer is correct. `->` is an SQL operator that performs an implicit outer join. As such, your query would look up the value of `"Column from another table"` using the value in `Schema.Table.Column` as the key to that table, or would return `NULL` if the lookup doesn't point at a valid row.